# Map from $\mathbb {R}$ to $\mathbb {R^2}$

Tags: real-analysis, functions

Is there a way to construct an injective function that map from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R^2}$? If yes, please give me an example. Thank you!

Comment: $x \mapsto (x,0)$ is injective from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}^2$. I guess you forgot something in your question.

Comment: I think you mean surjective.

Comment: If you meant surjective, there still is. There is a bijection between $\mathbb{R}^2$ and $\mathbb{R}$. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cardinal_number#Cardinal_multiplication

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Injective means that for $(x,y) \in \mathbb R^2$ and $a,b\in\mathbb R$ we have $f(a)=(x,y) = f(b) \Rightarrow a=b$ thus all we need is every $\mathbb R$ to go to a different point in $\mathbb R^2$. Any line through $\mathbb R^2$ will satisfy this (amongst others)

Thus $$f(a) = \left(2a-0.5,1.7-a\right)$$
is injective, for example.

Answer (score 0):

$f(x) = (x, 2){}$ is injective.